# Custom Application updater

Tags: c#, admin, installshield

I have created a code, which compares XML files on the client side (in PC) with the XML file located on the FTP server; where once it detects that client is running older version of the program, it will download the latest build (so that user has always up to date program).

Here is the trick. Due to the fact, that I am overwriting files at run-time, I had to create an external console application which is being called from the main app if user wants to update. This way, first console application is executed and afterwards main app is closed, so that no files are locked by the system (application's .exe file would otherwise be locked and we could not replace it with the new one).

This process runs perfectly, if it is being installed somewhere else other than under the system folder (by that I mean e.g. `C:\Program Files\` drive). If user has decided to install main application there, then suddenly my app crashes as it does not have admin privileges.

I am using Install Shield LE when disbursing this app, and users that are using this program are not administrators (which means that I go to every computer and type admin password when I/users install this program).

Is there a way, how to execute my updated console application with admin rights, or how to define via Install Shield that once this app has been executed, I always want it to be executed as admin?

Hope that my explanation has not been confusing. I am more than happy to share additional details if necessary, as I need to figure out how to solve this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you don't have an AD configuration as Emmanuel suggest, because in this case you would push the updates without any problems and would not have to design an automatic updater.

I don't know if InstallShield has something like this, but Advanced Installer has the support to install a dedicated [updater that runs as a service](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-elevated-updates.html), thus it has all the permissions required to install an application under Program Files.

Of course this means you need to replace your updater with the one from Advanced Installer and also that the initial installation of the application on the end user machines will still require admin credentials. (future installs can install silently, without the user's intervention)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the following line to your app manifest:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Documentation on the msdn is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

Comment: Note that it is unlikely to help OP due to "users that are using this program are not administrators" as their will not be able to provide password for the prompt.

Comment: Nope, the app.manifest file, in Visual Studio, right click project->Add Item-> Choose Application Manifest File

Comment: Yeah, as Alexei has just mentioned; I have tried to implement but when I tried to execute the program as regular user, it requested admin password from me. This will not work unfortunately

Comment: So your question is more how to get admin privileges without admin account ? Well, unless you're using some exploit, the system is not designed to allow that (hopefully for us).

Comment: Perhap's that might help if you're in an AD domain:  http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remote-install-windows-software/